# Universal .bashrc alias showing results of sysytemctl start command

Tags: bash, scripting, alias, init-script, bashrc

This is small .bashrc alias that allows me to see results of starting service

```
alias systemctl start apache='systemctl start apache && echo SUCCESS || echo failure'
```

How can i modify to work withl all `systemctl start` commands?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use alias. Use a shell function. Like this

```
function sysctl_start {
    systemctl start "$1" && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE
}
```

or even better

```
function sysctl_start {
    systemctl start "$1"
    systemctl status "$1"
}
```

If you want just special handling for start, but keep the name, write a wrapper

```
function systemctl {
    if [ "$2" = start ]; then
       shift
       /usr/bin/systemctl start "$@" && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAILURE"
    else
       /usr/bin/systemctl "$@"
    fi
}
```